# Schedule.Service erroring out while connecting to localhost

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a PowerShell script that connects to a list of servers, and queries that scheduled tasks. (Something similar to https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show_download/2094-get-scheduled-tasks-from-a-computer-remote-or-local) It used to work fine on a Windows 2008R2 server. However, on a new Windows Server 2012 R2 server, it is giving the below error. Strange thing it only happens when connecting to the local machine, no errors to remote servers. And it doesn't raise any errors when running under my account using administrative privileges.

https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2015/04/10/pstip-retrieve-scheduled-tasks-using-schedule-service-comobject/

This article says

> Unfortunately, unlike the Get-ScheduledTask cmdlet using this COMObject requires an elevated PowerShell console with administrative credentials.

But the script used to work just fine on Windows Server 2008 R2 servers.

Is there anything that can be tweaked to make the script work on 2012 R2 servers?

```
Exception calling "Connect" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
At C:\scripts\CheckSchedulers\CheckSchedulers.ps1:20 char:10
+         ($TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service).Connect($curSe ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

The error is raised by my code, using the code from spiceworks, it is reproducible.

Comment: For help with your code: show your.code.

Comment: The error can be observed with just one line ($TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service).Connect($servername)    
Works okay on 2008r2 servers, not 2012r2 servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `Schedule.Service` object, assign it to a variable, and then try to call a `Connect()` method on the *result of that assignment*. I would not expect this to work on any Windows or PowerShell version, and if it did on Server 2008 R2 that's most likely just incidental.

You need the `Schedule.Service` object in a variable (because you're going to need it for other operations as well), and you must call `Connect()` *on that object*, so you need to do this in two steps:

```
$TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
$TaskScheduler.Connect($servername)  # connect to remote Task Scheduler
```

If you're connecting to different servers in a loop you can re-use the object and just `Connect()` to the next server.

For connecting to the local Task Scheduler service just remove `$servername` and call the method without argument:

```
$TaskScheduler.Connect()  # connect to local Task Scheduler
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yHBqmK3.png Here is a screenshot, I tried what you suggested, but still getting an error connecting to localhost.

Comment: For connecting to the local service use `Connect()` without argument.

Comment: Thanks. That works out fine.
https://i.imgur.com/RwrP2ZG.png Any idea why querying for "Adobe Acrobat Update Task" is fine, but "Adobe Flash Player NPAPI Notifier" raises an exception?

Comment: You're getting a "permission denied" error, so I'd suspect that the permissions on that task don't give your user access. Check the permissions on the respective file in `C:\Windows\system32\Tasks`.